# Input array and loop it into dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

hello I have a problem with How to load an array and loop it into dataframe in pandas and i have a code like below :

```
Tiker = ['one', 'two', 'tree', 'four']
for Tiker in Tiker:
print(Tiker)

Output:
one
two
tree
four
```

The question is how to enter the array one by one into the link we want

```
url1 = 'www.data.com/' + Tiker
lm_json = requests.get(url1).json()
df_list=pd.read_html(lm_json["componentData"])
datafin = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
```

I want to use a *loop* in the code above and with the end result a separate dataframe from *Tiker = ['one', 'two', 'tree', 'four']* from the website that we take the data from

**Final Ouput :**

dataframe1 = one

dataframe2 = two

dataframe3 = tree

dataframe4 = four

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: does use variables, but the problem is how to use the array for the for loop in the code and pass it into dataframe this a different matter,

Comment: `read_html()` for json is unusual, but following does what I believe you are trying to do `pd.concat([pd.read_html(requests.get(f"https://www.data.com/{t}").json()["componentData"]) for t in ["one","two","three"]])`